# Order by a subtraction expression sql

Tags: sql

I would like to perform an ORDER BY in sql that sorts the returned rows by their distance from my integer of interest. The expression would be
`ORDER BY (constant - ColumnName) ASC` specifically, something like `ORDER BY (10 - Distance) ASC`. When I tried running this expression the distances were just sorted descending which is not what I am looking for.

Is this possible in sql?

Comment: What happened when you tried

Comment: Yes, it is possible. However, the constant will not make any difference when sorting. (Unless make it harder to optimize, so you will perhaps not use any index....)

Comment: @jarlh the data sorting was oddly sorted descending which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: `ORDER BY (10 - Distance) ASC` will give the same result as `ORDER BY (-Distance) ASC`, which is the same as `ORDER BY Distance DESC`.

Comment: Without example data to demonstrate the behaviour you're getting versus the behaviour you want, we're guessing, because your question is too vaguely worded. In SO, an example is worth a thousand words.

Comment: @jarlh you're right. It works. I idiotically thought that I was getting the wrong results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Distance from integer of interest" suggests that you want `abs()`:

```
ORDER BY ABS(constant - ColumnName) ASC
```

You are correct that the following are equivalent:

```
ORDER BY 10 - Distance
ORDER BY Distance DESC
```